# Do all Samsung NC10 netbooks have 3g modems

Tags: netbook, 3g

Do all Samsung nc10 netbooks have 3g sockets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO and it depends on request*   .

*This Features and specifications are subject to change without prior notification.

[Reference](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/pc-peripherals/notebook-computers/n-series/NP-NC10-KA02UK/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=spec&fullspec=F)